# How can I populate value in one list from another list in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I want to create a **leave** form list, where there are some fields like Name, Email id which need to be populated from **user information** list.

**User Information** list used for creating user in SharePoint. When we have all information in **User information** list then I need some fields value of it to be displayed to the corresponding fields in the **Leave** list.

I mean to say the user who is filling a new form whose information's should be pulled up from **user Information** list and filled into it into the **leave** form.

I don't know how I will achieve this. Please help.

Comment: Do you want to add a record in another list or populate data from the list and display in a new entry form  ?

Comment: populate data from the list and display in a new entry form. User infomation's (logged in user) should be populated and display into new entry Leave form.

Comment: What you have done so far ? getting an error ? or required first step to where to start from ?

Comment: I don't know how I will do this. No idea how I will populate the information from user information list and display into  new form of Leave list. Can you please provide some steps

Comment: Leave list has two fields Name and email id. I want these two fields should be come automatically from logged in user list (User information list).

Comment: I have seem to be another issue in this. I can't put a field called 'No of Leaves' in Active directory. Can we populate the information from one list and display into the second list. First list would be 'user information' and the second one would be 'Leave' list

Comment: One more question please, how can I put this code in the New form. Do I need to write Javascript code or something else.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current user details like name and Email address then you will require to query the Active directory.

To fetch the data from the Active directory follow this code .

**https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62929/get-current-users-department-name-and-manager-from-active-directory**

If you have developed a custom new form then you can write a code there and fetch and filldata in the appropriate firle

Comment: One more question please, how can I put this code in the New form and get it work done. Do I need to write Javascript code or something else

Comment: Also do I need to create a New form using SharePoint Designer instead of using the Default form to put the code. Because Default form doesn't contain the field in the page source. Please also help me on this.

Comment: You have to create custom form for this , i think